# Meteor Error using npm-container package on deployment time

Tags: meteor

I am using meteor 1.2.1 version.
I want to used node js package in meteor, So i add `npm-container` meteor package .
But after adding this package in meteor project, this give the below error on deployment time(mup deploy).

[101.100.1.200] - Invoking deployment process
[101.100.1.200] x Invoking deployment process: FAILED

### -----------------------------------STDERR-------------------------------

```
    RN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
    ../src/coroutine.cc: In function `void* find_thread_id_key(void*)':
    ../src/coroutine.cc:64:53: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >=
```

0 is always true [-Wtype-limits]
          for (pthread_key_t ii = coro_thread_key - 1; ii >= 0; --ii) {
                                                             ^
        ../src/coroutine.cc:90:3: warning: `thread_id' may be used uninitialized
 in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
           if (tls == thread_id) {
           ^
        js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left
Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0cu
rl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8456: Connection refused
        Latest deployment failed! Reverted back to the previous version.

### -----------------------------------STDOUT-------------------------------

```
    lk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk

    escape-string-regexp@1.0.3 node_modules/escape-string-regexp

    supports-color@0.2.0 node_modules/supports-color

    has-ansi@0.1.0 node_modules/has-ansi

    strip-ansi@0.3.0 node_modules/strip-ansi

    eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline

    type-of@2.0.1 node_modules/type-of

    amdefine@1.0.0 node_modules/amdefine

    asap@2.0.3 node_modules/asap

    underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

    meteor-promise@0.5.0 node_modules/meteor-promise

    promise@7.0.4 node_modules/promise

    source-map-support@0.3.2 node_modules/source-map-support

    semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

    source-map@0.1.32 node_modules/source-map

    fibers@1.0.5 node_modules/fibers
    Waiting for MongoDB to initialize. (5 minutes)
    { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_
```

FOUND' }
        connected
        Project-Name stop/waiting
        Project-Name start/running, process 23426
        Waiting for 100 seconds while app is booting up
        Checking is app booted or not?
        Project-Name stop/waiting
        Project-Name start/running, process 25162

Comment: I really suggest to upgrade to 1.3, then you will have `package.json` like in normal Node applications, and will be able to require() any npm modules you like

Comment: Thanks Alex for replay, but this is hard to update with 1.3 version now